# Is pre-order or post-order representation of BST unique?

Tags: algorithm

I know that in-order traversal of BST (binary search tree) is not unique. For example

```
in-order traversal = [a, b, c] where a < b < c

1)   b            
    / \
   a   c

2) a
    \
     b
      \
       c
Two different BSTs output same in-order traversal array.
```

I am not sure whether this is true for post-order traversal or pre-order traversal - I cannot find a counter example. Does pre-order or post-order traversal uniquely represent a BST?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Given a preorder traversal, the BST can be reconstructed as follows:

The first element must be a root. In a preorder, it is followed by the bunch of elements less than root (coming from left subtree), followed by the bunch of elements greater than root (coming from right subtree).

Find the partition point, and apply the same logic recursively to the left half (that would reconstruct the left subtree), and the right half (that would reconstruct the right subtree).

Ditto for postorder (the root is the last).

Answer (score -1):

It's not.

In pre-order for `[a, b]`, the root is always `a` but `b` can be either left or right.

Same goes for larger trees as well as post-order.

Comment: I'm confused. If elements are distinct and a < b, then by the property of BST, b is always in the right subtree given pre-order for [a,b]?

Comment: @Ted pre-order means the "node" goes before the subtrees. Once the node is `a`, either subtree can be `b` and the result would be the same. You can read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order_(NLR)

Comment: “Either subtree can be B” is not true when it’s a BST, isn’t it?